# Angular service promise first is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, service, promise

Today I started with Angular 2 and already came across an error I can't solve.

I have an 'opdracht' service which is loading data out of a mock file. The opdracht component is 4 times in the home component. The first is undefined and the last 3 are showing.

I think there is something wrong with the promise. But I can't figure out what. The code and the console error is down here.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Maarten

**Console error**

```
main.bundle.js:41251EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./OpdrachtComponent class OpdrachtComponent - inline template:0:3 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

**opdracht.ts**

```
export interface Opdracht {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**opdrachten.mock.ts**

```
import { Opdracht } from "./opdracht";

export const OPDRACHTEN: Opdracht[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Apple iDrive"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Lunchroom Bakker"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Augmented Albert"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Pecha Kucha"
 }
];
```

**opdrachten.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Opdracht} from "./opdracht";
import {OPDRACHTEN} from "./opdrachten.mock";

@Injectable()
export class OpdrachtenService {

  getOpdracht(id: any): Promise<Opdracht> {
    return Promise.resolve(OPDRACHTEN[id]);
  }
}
```

**opdracht.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {OpdrachtenService} from "../services/opdrachten/opdrachten.service";
import {Opdracht} from "../services/opdrachten/opdracht";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-opdracht',
  templateUrl: './opdracht.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./opdracht.component.scss'],
  providers: [OpdrachtenService]
})
export class OpdrachtComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() private id: any;

  protected opdracht: Opdracht;

  constructor(private opdrachtenService: OpdrachtenService) { }

  getOpdracht(): void {
    this.opdrachtenService.getOpdracht(this.id)
      .then((opdracht: Opdracht) => {
        this.opdracht = opdracht
      })
    ;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOpdracht();
  }
}
```

**opdracht.component.html**

```
<p>{{ opdracht.name }}</p>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-foto></app-foto>
<app-ik></app-ik>
<app-opdracht [id]="0"></app-opdracht>
<app-opdracht [id]="1"></app-opdracht>
<app-opdracht [id]="2"></app-opdracht>
<app-opdracht [id]="3"></app-opdracht>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: You are calling opdracht with id 0 but you don't have it in your mock file.

Comment: The input name 'id' is a bit misleading. I'm using it as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the safe-navigation operator to avoid errors when Angular evaluates the binding but async values have not yet arrived:

```
<p>{{ opdracht?.name }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear :)